# Ayuda con un problema de c, guardar operacion en variable

Tags: c

No guarda la operacion que se hace en printf, por ejemplo 2+2, no lo guarda en scanf, apenas estoy empezando

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main(){
float resultado;
printf("Introduce la operacion: ");
scanf("%f", resultado);
printf("El resultado de la operacion es: %f", resultado);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: edita su pregunta con ejemplo de que ingresas y que quieres obtener de resultado.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia la línea donde capturas el valor ingresado.

```
scanf("%f", &resultado);
```

Estro seria un ejemplo para sumar dos valores ingresados

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main(){
float valor1, valor2, resultado;
printf("Introduce el primer valor: ");
scanf("%f", valor1);
printf("Introduce el segundo valor: ");
scanf("%f", valor2);
resultado = valor1 + valor2;
printf("El resultado de la operacion es: %f", resultado);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pues avance un poco, pero por ejemplo pongo '5+5' pero solo me tira 5

Comment: Claro, esto sucede por que `scanf()` solo lee el primer dato que cumple con el tipo indicado `("%f")` el cual es `5`, si requieres hacer una suma la debes de programas con otra variable adicional y otro `scanf()`

Comment: Entonces como se hace una cuenta asi? o no se puede? para no hacer la calculadora que todos hacen que te pida si quieres sumar o restar, solo hacer operacion y resultado